# Why isn't the [appengine-api-1.0-sdk] scope "provided"?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Isn't this something the container (GAE platform) should provide?

Comment: This is a great question, In my experience the SDK API jar makes up about 30% of the entire war for an app, and being bundled in means that this impacts the startup time (as startup includes loading the war across the network). It would be great to get an answer from a googler.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps.But that would take away the ability to run a local version of your app on your dev machine, which is in my opinion a pretty important feature.

Comment: I suppose then it only gets packed into the WAR when runing locally, not when being deployed to GAE...?

Comment: My guess it is bundled so you use the GAE SDK version you specified instead of the latest one on the cloud, which could very well differ from your local env.

Comment: Its actually the API, not the implementation. You can see the actual version you're running on in your dashboard, and this usually updates before they release the next SDK version. This seemingly means that this jar does not control the version your code is running on.

Comment: @Nick the SDK version DOES NOT update automatically. that jar actually holds a fixed version of the GAE platform including everything you run when you deploy on you local env. And i mean everything: server, dependencies, etc. Without that you wouldn't be able to run an app locally.